# Using Struct to pass a variable Swift

Tags: swift, variables, struct

I'm trying to use a Struct to pass some variables that I get from a Facebook Graph Request such as email, name, gender, etc.
I've created the Struct ('fbDemographics') and the variables in 'ViewController' but I get an error when I try to call the struct and one of the variables in 'SecondViewController' (Type 'ViewController' has no member 'fbDemographics'). I've never used struct before so a bit baffled why I am getting this error. Thanks for any thoughts. The code for both view controllers is below:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    struct fbDemographics {

        static var relationship_status: String?
        static var gender: String?
        static var user_education_history: String?
        static var user_location: String?
        static var email: String?
        static var name: String?

    }     

    FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id, name, relationship_status, gender, user_location, user_education_history, email"]).start(completionHandler: { (connection, result, error) -> Void in
        if (error == nil){
            //let fbDetails = result as! NSDictionary
            //print(fbDetails)

            if let userDataDict = result as? NSDictionary {
                fbDemographics.gender = userDataDict["gender"] as? String
                fbDemographics.email = userDataDict["email"] as? String
                fbDemographics.name = userDataDict["name"] as? String
                fbDemographics.user_location = userDataDict["user_location"] as? String
                fbDemographics.user_education_history = userDataDict["user_education_history"] as? String
                fbDemographics.relationship_status = userDataDict["relationship_status"] as? String


                let myEducation = fbDemographics.user_education_history
                let myEmail = fbDemographics.email
                let myGender = fbDemographics.gender
                let myName = fbDemographics.name
                let myStatus = fbDemographics.relationship_status
                let myLocation = fbDemographics.user_location                   

                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "LoginToHome", sender: (Any).self)


            }


        }
```

SECOND VIEW CONTROLLER

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

@IBAction func verticalSliderChanged(_ sender: UISlider) {

        let currentValue = String(sender.value);

        sliderLabel.text = "\(currentValue)"

    func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        ***ViewController.fbDemographics.myEmail***

    }
}
```

Comment: There are a lot of things wrong with your current solution. I would search for some tutorials on passing data between view controllers.

Comment: I've been going through a lot of tutorials. Just not getting passing variables but I guess ill keep plugging away. Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: Your question have a lot of unnecessary code. Please, delete and keep only the important.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you've defined your `struct` *inside* `viewDidLoad`. So the scope is limited to that method. Move it out of `viewDidLoad`, but still in `ViewController`, and you should be able to access it from the `SecondViewController`. Obviously, you'll have to fix that reference to `myEmail`, too, because it's called `email`. Also, in your `SecondViewController` you should pull `viewDidLoad` implementation out of the `verticalSliderChanged` method; the `viewDidLoad` should be a top-level instance method of `SecondViewController`, not defined inside another method.

There are deeper problems here, though. Rather than using `struct` with `static` variables, you really should make those simple instance variables, create an instance of your `FbDemographics` type (note, start `struct` types with uppercase letter), and then pass this instance in [`prepare(for:sender:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621490-prepare).

---

For example, the right way to pass data would be to:

- eliminate `static` variables;
- give your `struct` a name that starts with uppercase letter;
- create instance of your `struct`; and
- pass this instance to the destination view controller in [`prepare(for:sender:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621490-prepare).

E.g.

```
struct FbDemographics {
    var relationshipStatus: String?
    var gender: String?
    var userEducationHistory: String?
    var userLocation: String?
    var email: String?
    var name: String?
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var demographics: FbDemographics?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        performRequest()   // I actually don't think you should be initiating this in `viewDidLoad` ... perhaps in `viewDidAppear`
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let destination = segue.destination as? SecondViewController {
            destination.demographics = demographics
        }
    }

    func performRequest() {
        FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id, name, relationship_status, gender, user_location, user_education_history, email"]).start { connection, result, error in
            guard let userDataDict = result as? NSDictionary, error == nil else {
                print("\(error)")
                return
            }

            self.demographics = FbDemographics(
                relationshipStatus: userDataDict["relationship_status"] as? String,
                gender: userDataDict["gender"] as? String,
                userEducationHistory: userDataDict["user_education_history"] as? String,
                userLocation: userDataDict["user_location"] as? String,
                email: userDataDict["email"] as? String,
                name: userDataDict["name"] as? String
            )

            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "LoginToHome", sender: self)
        }
    }

}
```

And then SecondViewController could:

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    var demographics: FbDemographics!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let value = demographics.email  // this should work fine here
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time to put up such a complete answer. I went through this and followed what you said. I don't have any errors which is a good first start. One question though; I wasn't sure what you meant when you said pass the instance (prepareforsegue). Thanks again.

Comment: For myriad reasons, it's inadvisable to declare `static` properties (in which every instance of `FbDemographics` will share the same value). You instead want to create an "instance" with the `let foo = FbDemographics(...)` syntax. Then, the question becomes how does `SecondViewController` gets a copy of this instance. So you have the `prepare(for:sender:)` confirm that the destination is a `SecondViewController`, and if so, assign the corresponding `demographics` property to be a copy of that original `FbDemographics` instance that we created above.